# mysql stored procedure , Use selected values from database

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a **stored procedure** in **mysql**. In it i am selecting some values from database using following statement ,

```
select version_id from version where version_name between '1.1' and '1.5'
```

Now i want to run a loop for all selected values from above statement means suppose above statement returns following row , 
           `version_id (1,5,3,7)` 
 so i want to run a loop  for values 1,5,3,7 .

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Please elaborate?  What are *all select values*?

Comment: You might not need the loop. The select itself offers you a loop.  But yes..elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you need to use Cursor element to loop in values

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CURSOR_LOOP()
BEGIN
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR
  select version_id where version_name between '1.1' and '1.5' 

OPEN C1;
read_loop: LOOP
  FETCH C1 INTO v_ID;
  IF done THEN
     LEAVE read_loop;
  END IF;
-- YOUR ACTION HERE                                            
END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
-- OTHERS ACTIONS
END;
```